# Upper() doesn't uppercase accented characters

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Within our postgres 12 database, using united_states.utf8 collation, we have a dataset with Spanish data that includes accented characters. However when we upper() the values in the field, unaccented characters are correctly uppercased, but accented character are not.

`upper('anuncio genérico para web del cliente')` gives `'ANUNCIO GENéRICO PARA WEB DEL CLIENTE'`

How can I correct this to get the expected result of `'ANUNCIO GENÉRICO PARA WEB DEL CLIENTE'`?

I have tried forcing the string into c and posix collations, but these are ANSI only.

Comment: You didn't specify your operating system. Perhaps the C library on that system is broken.

Comment: I can confirm the query works correctly on an AWS RDS instance as well as a local Docker instance of Postgres.

Comment: [Works with RedHat](https://dbfiddle.uk/VUylALor) and on my Windows laptop

Comment: This is running on a windows server OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem and a solution to it. My DB, as mentioned in the question, used `'English_United States.utf8'` collation as default to match the encoding of UTF8. However on a windows environment, the `'English_United Kingdom.1252'` collation works with UTF8 encoding, despite being specified for ANSI, and returns the uppercase characters as expected.

To resolve the issue I had to create the collation in the db using;

`CREATE COLLATION "English_United Kingdom.1252" (LC_COLLATE='English_United Kingdom.1252', LC_CTYPE='English_United Kingdom.1252');`

Which places it in the public schema. You can then manually correct the issue in queries by calling  `collate "English_United Kingdom.1252"` against any strings with accents, or use

`alter table [table_name] alter column [column_name] type text collate "English_United Kingdom.1252"`

Against any columns that have accented characters to fix the collation permanently. Unfortunately there is no way to change the default collation for a DB once it is created without doing a full backup, drop, and restore.